# .Net Application Spammed by 404 Errors - Elmah

Tags: .net, http-status-code-404, elmah

We recently deployed a change to our web application which is built in .net and running on AWS that included error logging using ELMAH. As a result after a few days we noticed we were getting spammed by a lot of requests that were showing up as 404 errors in the logs.

Should we be worried about all of these attempts and what exactly does it mean? Should any action be taken on our part to help prevent this from happening?

Based on what I found so far it looks like if you have PHP you might be more vulnerable.

See the attached screenshot for a small sample size of the errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone is scanning your application to see if there's any software installed they might want to try and hack. You can see because of the specific types of requests like those for `phpmyadmin`.

On one hand, this is fairly normal for a public facing website*. On the other hand I understand you would want to 'fix' this. One scenario would be to implement [throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/throttling) or [Rate Limiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting). There's quite a few scenario's you could think of, for instance blocking an IP as soon as it has too many 404 requests within a specified amount of time.

**Unfortunately we've come to a point where we say something like this is 'fairly normal'.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your budget is but utilizing Amazon's web application firewall would definitely weed allot of this out.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/tutorials-common-attacks.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/tutorials-4xx-blocking.html

Also take a look at this pre-built web application firewall template which utilizes AWS best practices for security and availability: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/aws-waf-security-automations/welcome.html

> ```
> Web Requests  Cost/Month
> 1 million     $14.65
> 10 million    $46.50
> 100 million   $79.00
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in one of the other answers, being scanned is a common issue for all public facing websites. There are proxy products available, which are able to filter out some of these requests, but nothing catches 100%.

My input to this would be to user [error filtering](https://elmah.github.io/a/error-filtering/) in ELMAH. You probably don't want to ignore every 404, since that could be caused by your own website too (and you want to know when that happens). Using filtering, you can create a combination of IPs and status codes to ignore.